# passing vector of pointers

Tags: c++, vector

I'm having a problem with my vector passed in a function as a parameter. I'm getting the following error:

```
void checkout(std::vector<InvoiceItem,std::allocator<InvoiceItem>>)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::vector<InvoiceItem *,std::allocator<InvoiceItem *>>' to 'std::vector<InvoiceItem,std::allocator<InvoiceItem>>'   classwork15 C:\Users\dhuan\source\repos\classwork15\classwork15\main.cpp
```

I called the vector

```
vector<InvoiceItem*> order;
```

I'm calling the function in my main, in a while loop.

```
    while (choice <= 4 && again == 'y')
    {
        if (choice == 1)
        {
            invoice = addToCart();
            cart.append(invoice);
            InvoiceItem* ptr = new InvoiceItem(invoice);
            order.push_back(ptr);
        }

        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            cart.display();
        }
        else if (choice == 3)
        {
            checkout(order); // <-here
        }
        cout << "1: add to order, 2: view cart, 3: checkout" << endl;
        cout << "Your choice: " << endl;
        cin >> choice;
        cout << endl;
    }
```

This is the function, if it helps:

```
void checkout(vector<InvoiceItem*> order)
{
    string name;
    char again = 'y';
    int orderNum = 1000;
    double total;
    cout << "Checking out" << endl;
    cout << "Enter name: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "INVOICE" << endl;
    cout << "Order Number: " << orderNum++ << endl;
    cout << "Customer: " << name << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "QTY \tDescription \t\tEach \tSubtotal" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < order.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << i + 1 << "\t" << order[i]->getDescription() << "\t\t" << order[i]->getPrice() << "\t" << order[i]->getTotal() << endl;
        total += order[i]->getTotal();
    }

    cout << "Total Due: ";
    cin >> total;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling this function from? What type of values are you passing to it? Please post a [mre].

Comment: Your function *definition* takes a `vector<InvoiceItem*>`, but the error claims the function is expecting a `vector<InvoiceItem>` instead, which means your function *declaration* is wrong and needs to be fixed.

Comment: The error message says you're trying to assign a `vector<InvoiceItem*>` to a `vector<InvoiceItem>`.  In fact, it explicitly says that in `main.cpp` (line number omitted by you) you declared `void checkout(vector<InvoiceItem>)` -- this does not match the definition presented in your question.

Comment: For this situation std::vector<InvoiceItem> is probably what you need anyway. 
Read https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines on how to write modern C++ (Specially P.2. try to avoid new/delete)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've distilled your question down to a minimum reproducible example.  If you were to remove *all* unnecessary junk from your program, you would have something like this:

```
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

class InvoiceItem {};

// (A)
void checkout(vector<InvoiceItem> order);

int main()
{
    vector<InvoiceItem*> order;
    checkout(order);               //<-- error occurs here
}

// (B)
void checkout(vector<InvoiceItem*> order)
{
}
```

Indeed, this gives the same compiler error.

The problem is that the declaration of the function that main() knows about contains an error.  So before the compiler even reaches your function definition, it parses `main` and immediately has a type mismatch.

The error message should not only tell you what line that happened on, but should also direct you to the line where it got the declaration in the first place.

Fast-forward to your function definition at (B).  Well, that's an entirely different function from what `main` knew about.  As such, it's called an *overload* -- it's a different function that happens to have the same name as (A).

```
void checkout(vector<InvoiceItem> order);
```

So, in case it's not now obvious, the function signature at (A) should be made to match the one at (B).  That way, it refers to the *same* function that `main` knows about.  And so even though the function hasn't yet been defined while the compiler is parsing `main`, it at least refers to the correct function with the correct parameter type.